# Compiler error while installing py-bcrypt in Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, compiler-construction, mingw, flask

I need to install the Flask module `flask-bcrypt` which requires `py-bcrypt`. When I try to install it, an error occurs at:

```
C:\Users\Param\Downloads\py-bcrypt-0.3>python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing py_bcrypt.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to py_bcrypt.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to py_bcrypt.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'py_bcrypt.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'py_bcrypt.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win32\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
error: don't know how to compile C/C++ code on platform 'nt' with 'MinGW32' comp
iler
```

What is causing this problem?

Previously, I had installed MinGW32 in my Windows 7 64 bit machine. Is the problem occuring because MinGW is 32 bit and Windows is 64 bit? If so, what should I do to resolve this issue? (How can I use MinGW 64 bit in my machine?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These libraries are already compiled and available somewhere. Someone already uploaded compiled versions for windows. I was able to run flask-bcrypt in Windows with the files.

You just throw it in your flask/scripts/python packages folder.

It was answered in the Flask subreddit **with a location to download the libraries you need**:

http://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/15q5xj/anyone_have_a_working_version_of_flaskbcrypt_for/

Comment: py-bcrypt 0.4 wheels just added in the same location.

Comment: That's only python 2 - are there python 3 binaries?

Answer (score 0):

Have a loot at [these MinGW binaries](http://www.develer.com/oss/GccWinBinaries). It should be a version of MinGW GCC specifically taylored for building Python extension modules.

> this installer tries to fix all the problems with compiling Python distutils extensions with GCC

Comment: now its giving new error: "command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1"

Comment: @Man8Blue py-bcrypt is an extension for bcrypt, meaning you will need the bcrypt libraries built before you can build it. if you have issues setting that up, you might be better off looking for binaries.